# Calling a different method inside of another method

Tags: python, function, openpyxl, dry

Somewhat new to Python but this is a question about writing functions without repeating oneself.

Using `openpyxl` I've created a document class and a workbook (`wb`) with 3 sheets inside:

```
self.sheet1 = self.wb['sheet1']
self.sheet2 = self.wb['sheet2']
self.sheet3 = self.wb['sheet3']
```

I also have a function in this class that looks through rows of `sheet3` for particular text.

```
def find_text_row_number(self, text):
    text_row_number = set([])

    for row in self.sheet3.iter_rows(self.sheet3.min_row,self.sheet3.max_row):
        for cell in row:
            if cell.value == text:
                text_row_number.add(cell.row)

    return sorted(text_row_number)
```

My question is: **How can I call this function elsewhere in the program and have it search `sheet2`, instead of `sheet3`?** Have tried looking into decorators and also using a default value (`sheet=self.sheet3`), but this raises an error because `self` has not yet been defined.

Is there maybe a more efficient way to write this particular function? Or some aspect of Python I'm missing that could help out here?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
def find_text_row_number(self, text, sheet_name='sheet1'):
    text_row_number = set([])
    sheet = getattr(self, sheet_name)

    for row in sheet.iter_rows(sheet.min_row, sheet.max_row):
        for cell in row:
            if cell.value == text:
                text_row_number.add(cell.row)

    return sorted(text_row_number)
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use separate variables, put all the sheets in a list. Then you can access the one you want with an index.

The first code would initialize the list:

```
self.sheets = [self.wb['sheet1'], self.wb['sheet2'], self.wb['sheet3']]
```

Then your other method can take an optional index.

```
def find_text_row_number(self, text, sheet_num = 3):
    sheet = self.sheets[sheet_num-1]
    text_row_number = set([])

    for row in sheet.iter_rows(sheet.min_row,sheet.max_row):
        for cell in row:
            if cell.value == text:
                text_row_number.add(cell.row)

    return sorted(text_row_number)
```

When you want to process `sheet2`, use

```
x.find_text_row_number("text", sheet_num = 2)
```